# Searching multiple sheets in an excel C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, listbox

The code here grabs a name in my listbox(employeebox) and deletes the entire row on that sheet. This works and there are no errors.. My problem is that I have 19 different sheets that need to be checked, but I can only check 1 at a time with this code.. "Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets[2];".. Is there any way that I can check all the sheets once the Delete button is clicked? I greatly appreciate anyone's help.

```
private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create excel
    Excel.Application xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\\SAMPLE.xlsx");
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets[2];

    //search within excel
    Excel.Range usedRanage = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
    foreach (Excel.Range row in usedRanage)
    {
        //grab name once selected in box
        if (employeeBox.SelectedItem.Equals(row.Value))
        {
            row.EntireRow.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);

            MessageBox.Show("Employee Deleted.");
        }

    }

    xlexcel.DisplayAlerts = false;

    xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\SAMPLE.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    xlWorkBook.Close();
    xlexcel.Quit();

    releaseObject(xlexcel);
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with going from sheet to sheet?

Comment: Hello I'm just a coder for fun... you will have to loop thru all the existing sheets in the work book... something like.... foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in workBook.Worksheets)

Comment: @DangerZone - Way too much code.

Comment: Hello! @JohnG That's what I was thinking too.. Which reads it like the rows correct?

Comment: If it's too much code, break it out into another method so you can repeat it... Looping over your worksheet to do *the same thing* should not take "way too much" extra code from what you've done.

Comment: That is correct. There are several good post here on how to do this. Here is one. [How to iterate through Excel Worksheets only extracting data from specific columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156951/how-to-iterate-through-excel-worksheets-only-extracting-data-from-specific-colum)

Comment: Once again, you rock! @JohnG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create excel
        Excel.Application xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\\SAMPLE.xlsx");
        int[] Cols = { 1 };
        Excel.Range curRange;

        foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in xlWorkBook.Worksheets)
        {
            foreach (Excel.Range row in sheet.UsedRange.Rows)
            {
                foreach (int c in Cols)
                {
                    curRange = (Excel.Range)row.Cells[1, 1];
                    if (curRange.Cells.Value != null)
                    {      
                         if (employeeBox.SelectedItem.Equals(sheet.Cells[row.Row, c].Value.ToString()))
                         { 
                            row.EntireRow.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);

                            MessageBox.Show("Employee Deleted.");
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
             xlexcel.DisplayAlerts = false;

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\SAMPLE.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            xlWorkBook.Close();
            xlexcel.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlexcel);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);


    }
```

Comment: This works.. Goes through all the Sheets, then deletes the one I selected.