# How to iterate through Excel only extracting data from specific columns

Tags: c#, excel

I need to extract row data from specific columns in an xls file and add each row to a list as I iterate. I looked on this site and found [How to iterate through Excel Worksheets only extracting data from specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156951/how-to-iterate-through-excel-worksheets-only-extracting-data-from-specific-colum), but I am not sure how to modify to allow adding to a list while going through each iteration.

```
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Temp\Sample\Sample.xls");
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;



        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {
                //Not sure if I need to iterate this way or not



            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you maybe show the `Sample.xls` and exactly explain what you're trying to extract?

Comment: I am not sure how to add the Sample file. It looks like: (First line are headers)
(Line 1) Date          Group    Description       Agency 
(Line 2) 11/07/2016   1         Pessoa Fisica    1306

Answer (score 0):

In the second loop, you want to add a conditional statement (If-then-else) code to check if you are at the column from which you want to extract your data.

In your conditional statement where your condition is met positively with the criteria for extraction, you want to insert your extraction code.  For Example look at the following pseudo code:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
        {
            If extraction condition 
            then 
              extraction code
            else 
              keep looking code
            end


        }
    }
```

BTW you may want to look into the "Look Up" function in Excel