# Why is my code not saving the correct worksheet?

Tags: excel, powershell

I have this following Powershell script to convert the 2nd sheet on a XLSB file to CSV.

```
Function XLSBtoCSV ($Path)

{
    foreach($File in (Get-childItem $Path -Filter "*.xlsb"))
        {

        $pwd = $Path

        $excelFile = "$pwd\" + $File

        $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

        $Excel.Visible = $false

        $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

        $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)
        $ws = $wb.Worksheets.item(2)
        $ws.SaveAs("$pwd\" + $File.BaseName + "-" + $ws.name + ".csv", 6)

        $Excel.Quit()
    }

}


$FilePath = Get-Location

XLSBtoCSV -Path $FilePath
```

This script used to work but somehow now it only saves the last worksheet (sheet 3). I have tried to change to different sheet number but every time, the last worksheet is saved.

Comment: Can you add `$wb.Worksheets | select name` after `$wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)` and show the output? I was unable to reproduce that issue on my side.

Comment: I added the $ws.name to keep track of what worksheet being selected. The name is actually correct, however the file is still saved with data from the last worksheet.

Comment: I mean - can you add the output of that command to your question? As mentioned, the code works for me.

Comment: It works for my smaller size file. Only this particular type of files where it doesn't work. The output says Name ----- Summary, Data, Data Dictionary. Those are the names of all 3 worksheets. Do I expect to get one name only?

Comment: If that works for smaller file, then the code is correct. Perhaps there's something wrong with your files, but I'm not able to reproduce that so it's difficult to point what's the issue. I asked about `$wb.Worksheets | select name` as I expected that the worksheets are not in correct order and you're choosing the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

Very close. You need to loop through the worksheet items instead of just calling items(2) as covered in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156951/how-to-iterate-through-excel-worksheets-only-extracting-data-from-specific-colum):

```
Function XLSBtoCSV ($Path)
{
    foreach($File in (Get-childItem $Path -Filter "*.xlsb"))
        {

        $pwd = $Path

        $excelFile = "$pwd\" + $File

        try{
            $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

            $Excel.Visible = $false

            $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

            $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)

            # source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156951/how-to-iterate-through-excel-worksheets-only-extracting-data-from-specific-colum
            foreach($ws in $wb.Worksheets)
            {
                $ws.SaveAs("$pwd\" + $File.BaseName + "-" + $ws.name + ".csv", 6)
            }
        } 
        finally 
        {
            # close/dispose all the open parts of Excel
            if($Excel) 
            { 
                $Excel.Quit()
            }
        }
    }

}


$FilePath = Get-Location

XLSBtoCSV -Path $FilePath
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I gave this a try but it would save every worksheet available on the workbook whereas I only need to save the 2nd worksheet.

Comment: Possibly a [Zero-based_numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) system so 2nd sheet = ```$wb.Worksheets.item(1)```

Comment: @lloyd it's not zero-based in `$wb.Worksheets.item()`